# new computer crash in 3d

Tags: windows, crash

i just bought and put together a new computer

Asus P8H61-M LE/CSM motherboard
Intel I5-2500K 3.3Ghz Socket 1155 Processor
Kingston DDR3 1333 4GB
sata dvd
sata hard drive

using the built in INtel HD Graphics 3000 and it seemed to be working ok

get a crash in world of warcraft. a hard crash, no wow errors or windows errors just weird pattern on screen and repeating sound so i have to reset computer

i set bios to default and it seemed to fix it but it still crashes just not as often as when set to Asus Optimal in bios

downloaded 3d mark vantage and i got the same crash when running that

so i guess it is a hardware problem? or i have to set something in bios? disable power saving?

dxdiag says directx11 but when i tried to run 3dmark 11 it says no dx11 hardware found... though wow does run in dx11 mode... the crash hap

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 5/4/2011, 15:55:16
       Machine name: RAGE
   Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Rakka
       System Model: Rage
               BIOS: BIOS Date: 02/05/10 19:13:52 Ver: 08.00.10
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.3GHz
             Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 2986MB RAM
          Page File: 794MB used, 5176MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 2: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 3: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
       Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
          Chip type: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
           DAC type: Internal
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0112&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_09
     Display Memory: 1301 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 64 MB
      Shared Memory: 1237 MB
       Current Mode: 1920 x 1200 (32 bit) (59Hz)
       Monitor Name: SyncMaster T240,SyncMaster Magic T240(Digital)
      Monitor Model: SyncMaster
         Monitor Id: SAM0422
        Native Mode: 1920 x 1200(p) (59.950Hz)
        Output Type: DVI
        Driver Name: igdumdx32.dll,igd10umd32.dll,igd10umd32.dll
Driver File Version: 8.15.0010.2361 (English)
     Driver Version: 8.15.10.2361
        DDI Version: 10.1
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.1
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 5/4/2011 12:19:20, 577024 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: Yes
    WHQL Date Stamp: 
  Device Identifier: {D7B78E66-4252-11CF-CA7A-47A4A9C2C535}
          Vendor ID: 0x8086
          Device ID: 0x0112
          SubSys ID: 0x844D1043
        Revision ID: 0x0009
 Driver Strong Name: oem10.inf:Intel.Mfg:iSNBD0:8.15.10.2361:pci\ven_8086&dev_0112
     Rank Of Driver: 00E62001
        Video Accel: ModeMPEG2_A ModeMPEG2_C ModeWMV9_C ModeVC1_C 
   Deinterlace Caps: {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
       D3D9 Overlay: Supported
            DXVA-HD: Supported
       DDraw Status: Enabled
         D3D Status: Enabled
         AGP Status: Enabled

-------------
Sound Devices
-------------
            Description: Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)
 Default Sound Playback: Yes
 Default Voice Playback: Yes
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0887&SUBSYS_10438445&REV_1003
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 65535
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: HdAudio.sys
         Driver Version: 6.01.7601.17514 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: Yes
          Date and Size: 11/20/2010 06:00:21, 304128 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Microsoft
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

            Description: Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device)
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0887&SUBSYS_10438445&REV_1003
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 65535
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: HdAudio.sys
         Driver Version: 6.01.7601.17514 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: Yes
          Date and Size: 11/20/2010 06:00:21, 304128 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Microsoft
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

            Description: Speakers (USB Audio Device)
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: USB\VID_0D8C&PID_000C&REV_0100&MI_00
        Manufacturer ID: 65535
             Product ID: 65535
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: USBAUDIO.sys
         Driver Version: 6.01.7601.17514 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: Yes
          Date and Size: 11/20/2010 05:59:44, 80768 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: Microsoft
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No

---------------------
Sound Capture Devices
---------------------
            Description: Microphone (High Definition Audio Device)
  Default Sound Capture: Yes
  Default Voice Capture: Yes
            Driver Name: HdAudio.sys
         Driver Version: 6.01.7601.17514 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: 11/20/2010 06:00:21, 304128 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x1
           Format Flags: 0xFFFFF

            Description: Microphone (USB Audio Device)
  Default Sound Capture: No
  Default Voice Capture: No
            Driver Name: USBAUDIO.sys
         Driver Version: 6.01.7601.17514 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: 11/20/2010 05:59:44, 80768 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x1
           Format Flags: 0xFFFFF

-------------------
DirectInput Devices
-------------------
      Device Name: Mouse
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: n/a
Vendor/Product ID: n/a
        FF Driver: n/a

      Device Name: Keyboard
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: n/a
Vendor/Product ID: n/a
        FF Driver: n/a

      Device Name: Microsoft® Digital Media Keyboard 3000
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: 0x0
Vendor/Product ID: 0x045E, 0x0730
        FF Driver: n/a

      Device Name: Microsoft® Digital Media Keyboard 3000
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: 0x0
Vendor/Product ID: 0x045E, 0x0730
        FF Driver: n/a

      Device Name: Microsoft® Comfort Mouse 4500
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: 0x0
Vendor/Product ID: 0x045E, 0x076C
        FF Driver: n/a

      Device Name: ?
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: 0x0
Vendor/Product ID: 0x0D8C, 0x000C
        FF Driver: n/a

Poll w/ Interrupt: No

-----------
USB Devices
-----------
+ USB Root Hub
| Vendor/Product ID: 0x8086, 0x1C2D
| Matching Device ID: usb\root_hub20
| Service: usbhub
| Driver: usbhub.sys, 11/20/2010 06:01:09, 258560 bytes
| Driver: usbd.sys, 7/13/2009 19:51:05, 5888 bytes
| 
+-+ Generic USB Hub
| | Vendor/Product ID: 0x8087, 0x0024
| | Location: Port_#0001.Hub_#0001
| | Matching Device ID: usb\class_09
| | Service: usbhub
| | Driver: usbhub.sys, 11/20/2010 06:01:09, 258560 bytes

----------------
Gameport Devices
----------------

------------
PS/2 Devices
------------
+ HID Keyboard Device
| Vendor/Product ID: 0x045E, 0x0730
| Matching Device ID: hid_device_system_keyboard
| Service: kbdhid
| Driver: kbdhid.sys, 11/20/2010 05:50:10, 28160 bytes
| Driver: kbdclass.sys, 7/13/2009 21:20:36, 42576 bytes
| 
+ Terminal Server Keyboard Driver
| Matching Device ID: root\rdp_kbd
| Upper Filters: kbdclass
| Service: TermDD
| Driver: i8042prt.sys, 7/13/2009 19:11:24, 80896 bytes
| Driver: kbdclass.sys, 7/13/2009 21:20:36, 42576 bytes
| 
+ HID-compliant mouse
| Vendor/Product ID: 0x045E, 0x076C
| Matching Device ID: hid_device_system_mouse
| Service: mouhid
| Driver: mouhid.sys, 7/13/2009 19:45:08, 26112 bytes
| Driver: mouclass.sys, 7/13/2009 21:20:44, 41552 bytes
| 
+ Terminal Server Mouse Driver
| Matching Device ID: root\rdp_mou
| Upper Filters: mouclass
| Service: TermDD
| Driver: termdd.sys, 11/20/2010 08:30:12, 53120 bytes
| Driver: sermouse.sys, 7/13/2009 19:45:08, 19968 bytes
| Driver: mouclass.sys, 7/13/2009 21:20:44, 41552 bytes

------------------------
Disk & DVD/CD-ROM Drives
------------------------
      Drive: C:
 Free Space: 355.3 GB
Total Space: 374.4 GB
File System: NTFS
      Model: WDC WD5000AAKX-001CA0 ATA Device

      Drive: D:
 Free Space: 52.6 GB
Total Space: 102.4 GB
File System: NTFS
      Model: WDC WD5000AAKX-001CA0 ATA Device

      Drive: E:
      Model: ASUS DRW-24B1ST   a ATA Device
     Driver: c:\windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 04:38:10, 108544 bytes

--------------
System Devices
--------------
     Name: Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1C26
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C26&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05\3&11583659&0&E8
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\usbehci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 05:59:43, 42496 bytes
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\usbport.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 06:00:06, 284672 bytes
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\usbhub.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 06:01:09, 258560 bytes

     Name: Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 Port SATA AHCI Controller - 1C02
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C02&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05\3&11583659&0&FA
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\msahci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 08:30:01, 28032 bytes
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\pciidex.sys, 6.01.7600.16385 (English), 7/13/2009 21:19:03, 42560 bytes
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\atapi.sys, 6.01.7600.16385 (English), 7/13/2009 21:26:15, 21584 bytes
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\ataport.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 08:29:12, 132992 bytes

     Name: Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller - 1C22
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C22&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05\3&11583659&0&FB
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0112&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_09\3&11583659&0&10
   Driver: n/a

     Name: High Definition Audio Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C20&SUBSYS_84451043&REV_05\3&11583659&0&D8
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\hdaudbus.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 05:59:29, 108544 bytes

     Name: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Intel(R) Core(TM) Processor Family PCI Express Root Port - 0101
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0101&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_09\3&11583659&0&08
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\pci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 08:30:06, 153984 bytes

     Name: Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 - 1C1A
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C1A&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5\3&11583659&0&E5
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\pci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 08:30:06, 153984 bytes

     Name: 2nd Generation Intel(R) Core(TM) Processor Family DRAM Controller - 0100
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0100&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_09\3&11583659&0&00
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 82801 PCI Bridge - 244E
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_244E&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5\3&11583659&0&E4
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\pci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 08:30:06, 153984 bytes

     Name: Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 - 1C16
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C16&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5\3&11583659&0&E3
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\pci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 08:30:06, 153984 bytes

     Name: PCI standard PCI-to-PCI bridge
Device ID: PCI\VEN_1B21&DEV_1080&SUBSYS_84621043&REV_01\4&37EA4451&0&00E4
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\pci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 08:30:06, 153984 bytes

     Name: Intel(R) H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Interface Controller - 1C5C
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C5C&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05\3&11583659&0&F8
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\msisadrv.sys, 6.01.7600.16385 (English), 7/13/2009 21:20:43, 13888 bytes

     Name: Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 - 1C14
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C14&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5\3&11583659&0&E2
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\pci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 08:30:06, 153984 bytes

     Name: Ethernet Controller
Device ID: PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_84321043&REV_06\4&1D7623A1&0&00E2
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Management Engine Interface - 1C3A
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C3A&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_04\3&11583659&0&B0
   Driver: n/a

     Name: Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 - 1C12
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C12&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5\3&11583659&0&E1
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\pci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 08:30:06, 153984 bytes

     Name: Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1C2D
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C2D&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_05\3&11583659&0&D0
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\usbehci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 05:59:43, 42496 bytes
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\usbport.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 06:00:06, 284672 bytes
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\usbhub.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 06:01:09, 258560 bytes

     Name: Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 - 1C10
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C10&SUBSYS_844D1043&REV_B5\3&11583659&0&E0
   Driver: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\pci.sys, 6.01.7601.17514 (English), 11/20/2010 08:30:06, 153984 bytes

------------------
DirectShow Filters
------------------

... removed to make room...

---------------
EVR Power Information
---------------
Current Setting: {5C67A112-A4C9-483F-B4A7-1D473BECAFDC} (Quality) 
  Quality Flags: 2576
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow half deinterlace
    Allow scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 100
  Balanced Flags: 1424
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow batching
    Force half deinterlace
    Force scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 50
  PowerFlags: 1424
    Enabled:
    Force throttling
    Allow batching
    Force half deinterlace
    Force scaling
    Decode Power Usage: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the symptoms you described, there’s a few things you need to do and check.

1. Make sure that the supplementary power-cable for your video adapter (probably a [standard molex connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMsoM.jpg)) is plugged into the [motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4GBH.jpg).
2. Run a [memory testing utility](http://www.memtest.org/) to check your RAM for problems. (Windows 7 has one [built-in](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/715-memory-diagnostics-tool.html).)
3. 1. Use a temperature monitoring utility to check your [system, CPU,](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and [graphics adapter](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) temperatures.
   2. Make sure that your system has sufficient air-flow through it to keep things (especially the CPU and motherboard chipsets) cool. Clean out any dust that has clogged up the heat sinks.
4. Observe results and compare. Report back for further help.

Answer (score 0):

DirectX shows DX11 because that's the software you have installed.  That has no bearing on the actual support of your hardware for it (it doesn't support it).

That said, this could potentially be a problem with the graphics hardware, yes.  If this is a clean installation and a brand new motherboard, I'd just RMA the motherboard and see if another works better.

Comment: the graphics hardware is on the cpu in this case i believe... hard to know where the problem lies...

Comment: I'd still start with the motherboard, just due to the incredibly low failure rate of Intel processors.